# How to retrieve data from firestore to display in multi select form field

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am new in flutter. I am trying to fetch a list of symptoms from firestore and display it in 'MultiSelectFormField'. How can I make it? What should I add?

```
MultiSelectFormField(
  autovalidate: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
  chipBackGroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
  chipLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
  dialogTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  checkBoxActiveColor: Colors.blue[900],
  checkBoxCheckColor: Colors.white,
  dialogShapeBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))),
  title: Text(
            "Symptoms",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),
         ),
         validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.length == 0) {
              return 'Please select one or more symptoms';
            }
            return null;
         },
         dataSource: ['value': symptomsList],
         textField: 'value',
         valueField: 'value',
         okButtonLabel: 'OK',
         cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
         hintWidget: Text('Please choose one or more symptoms'),
         initialValue: _symptoms,
         onSaved: (value) {
         if (value == null) return;
            setState(() {
              _symptoms = value;
       });
   },
),
```

Comment: Did yuo try anything yet? If not, this is probably a good place to start: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage

Comment: can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## **Important**

It is important that you have registered your app in your firebase project and have added the packages: [Firebase Core](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core) and [Cloud Firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) to your **pubspec.yaml** file

---

## **Retrieve**

### If you use documents as symptoms:

To Retrieve data from cloud firestore make sure that you have imported the cloud firestore package

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

After you done that create a function named `getDataFromFirestore()`

```
getDataFromFirestore(var collection, var data) async {

  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(collection)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
      // here we set the data to the data
      data = value.docs;
      });

 

}
```

After we have done that we can use the function in auer initstate:

```
    List symptoms = [];
    
      ...
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        asyncTasks() async {
          var data;

          await getDataFromFirestore("symptoms", data);

          // here we fill up the list symptoms
          for(var item in data) {
            symptoms.add(item.data()["name"]);
          }
          setState(() {});
        }
    
      asyncTasks();
      
      }
```

---

### When you use a list in a document as symptoms:

To Retrieve data from cloud firestore make sure that you have imported the cloud firestore package

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

After you done that create a function named `getDataFromFirestore()`

```
// the document Id is the id from the document where the symptoms list is in
    getDataFromFirestore(var collection, var data, var documentId) async {
  
      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection(collection)
              .doc(documentId)
              .get()
              .then((value) {
          // here we set the data to the data
          data = value.data();
          });
    
     
    
    }
```

After we have done that we can use the function in auer initstate:

```
    List symptoms = [];
    
      ...
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        asyncTasks() async {
          var data;

          await getDataFromFirestore("symptoms", data);

          // here we fill up the list symptoms
          for(var item in data) {
            symptoms.add(item["name"]);
          }
          setState(() {});
        }
    
      asyncTasks();
      
      }
```

---

## **Display**

```
MultiSelectFormField(
  autovalidate: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
  chipBackGroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
  chipLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
  dialogTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  checkBoxActiveColor: Colors.blue[900],
  checkBoxCheckColor: Colors.white,
  dialogShapeBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))),
  title: Text(
            "Symptoms",
            style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),
         ),
         validator: (value) {
            if (value == null || value.length == 0) {
              return 'Please select one or more symptoms';
            }
            return null;
         },
        // you can simply use the list
         dataSource: ['value': symptoms[0]],
         textField: 'value',
         valueField: 'value',
         okButtonLabel: 'OK',
         cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
         hintWidget: Text('Please choose one or more symptoms'),
         initialValue: _symptoms,
         onSaved: (value) {
         if (value == null) return;
            setState(() {
              _symptoms = value;
       });
   },
),
```

---

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you. But in the MultiSelectFormField, if i put dataSource: [{'value': symptoms.toString()}], and it only display "[]" as the option. If i put dataSource:  [{'value': symptoms}],, it display error E/flutter ( 8698): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String?'

Comment: sorry for the mistake: the empty list is probably because you don't have a setState(() {}); after populating the list and please use this code instead:

```dataSource: ['value': symptoms[0]],
```

Comment: sorry again. How should i solve this? RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0, Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'. Is it i fail to retrieve the data from db?

Comment: do you can explain your error: a little bit of code, where the error comes from...?

Comment: for(var item in data) {symptoms.add(item["name"]);} the error is about at here. but I already found the answer for this problem. I use stream builder. Thank you so much

Comment: great to hear that

Comment: can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 0):

firstly, declare the stream

```
final Stream<QuerySnapshot> symptomsStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('symptoms').snapshots();
```

Then use the stream builder to query the symptoms stream. Declare symptoms list and fill up the list symptoms. In the `datasource`, use `for`to display the list item one by one.

```
StreamBuilder(
  stream: symptomsStream,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasError){
      print('Something went wrong');
    }
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting){
      return const Center(
         child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    }
                          
    final List symptomsList = [];
    //fill up the list symptoms                      
    snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot document){
      Map a = document.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
      symptomsList.add(a['name']);
      a['id'] = document.id;
     }).toList();

     return MultiSelectFormField(
       autovalidate: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
       chipBackGroundColor: Colors.blue[900],
       chipLabelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
        dialogTextStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        checkBoxActiveColor: Colors.blue[900],
        checkBoxCheckColor: Colors.white,
        dialogShapeBorder: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12.0))),
        title: Text(
          "Symptoms",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize:20),
        ),
        validator: (value) {
          if (value == null || value.length == 0) {
            return 'Please select one or more symptoms';
          }
          return null;
        },
        dataSource: [
          for (String i in symptomsList) {'value' : i}
        ], 
        textField: 'value',
        valueField: 'value',
        okButtonLabel: 'OK',
        cancelButtonLabel: 'CANCEL',
        hintWidget: Text('Please choose one or more symptoms'),
        initialValue: _symptoms,
        onSaved: (value) {
        if (value == null) return;
        setState(() {
        _symptoms = value;
      }
     );
    },
   );
  }
),
```